# The inclusion map $i:U\to M$ induce a linear isomorphism $di_p : T_pU \to T_pM$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $U$ be open subset of smooth manifold $M$,then we have the inclusion map $i:U\to M$,then we know it induce the linear isomorphism $di_p:T_pU \to T_pM$.

We can prove it using the fact that local function $f\in C^\infty(U)$ can be extended to $\bar{f}\in C^\infty(M)$.Which can be found in all the textbook(For example Lee's smooth manifold textbook Proposition 3.9).

I found another proof,but I guess there must be something wrong.I do as follows:

Take $p\in U$ then there exist a smooth chart around $p$ that is $(O,\varphi)$.Since $U$ is open submanifold ,we know this smooth chart also lies in altalas of $M$ ,take this chart ,then we have the coordinate representation of $\hat{i} = \varphi\circ i\circ\varphi^{-1} = \text{Id}$ which is identity map,we know $d\hat{i}_p = \text{Id}_p$ which is isomorphism.

And differential of diffeomorphism $\varphi$ is also isomorphism,hence we have differential  $di_p$ an isomorphism by chain rule.

I don't know where goes wrong?

Comment: Looks OK to me. Why should it be wrong?

Comment: This theorem says tangent vector only has local effect on function.which is very important result,It should not be this simple proof I guess?

Comment: Ah, I see. This is indeed important, but in a way it should be a tautology. If we define a tangent vector as a differentiation, it's not a surprise that its action on a given function depends only its infinitesimal behavior. So there's no problem in finding a very simple argument for this.

Comment: thanks  $\ \ \ $

Comment: It may be useful to point out that one can define a tangent vector not as a differentation of $f \in C^\infty(M)$, but as a differentiation of germs ([look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics))). This way, our result is already a part of the definition. Another advantage is that this generalizes to e.g. complex manifolds, where we don't have cut-off functions.